# Limit size of temporary tables (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I'm managing a PostgreSQL database server for some users who need to create temporary tables. One user accidentally sent a query with ridiculously many outer joins, and that completely filled the disk up.

PostgreSQL has a `temp_file_limit` parameter but it seems to me that it is not relevant:

> It should be noted that disk space used for **explicit temporary tables**, as opposed to temporary files used behind-the-scenes in query execution, does not count against this limit.

Is there a way then to put a limit on the size on disk of "explicit" temporary tables? Or limit the row count? What's the best approach to prevent this?

Comment: Probably better to ask this at https://dba.stackexchange.com it's almost certainly off-topic here.

Comment: The [diskquota extension](https://github.com/greenplum-db/diskquota) claims it can do this

Answer (score 1):

The only way to limit a table's size in PostgreSQL is to put it in a tablespace on a file system of an appropriate size.

Since temporary tables are created in the default tablespace of the database you are connected to, you have to place your database in that size restricted tablespace. To keep your regular tables from being limited in the same way, you'd have to explicitly create them in a different, less limited tablespace. Make sure that your user has no permissions on that less limited tablespace.

This is a rather unappealing solution, so maybe you should rethink your requirement. After all, the user could just as well fill up the disk by inserting the data into a permanent table.